# c# webapi: Await Task.Run vs more granualar await

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm using async/await in WebApi Controllers according to this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx

Hava look at this simplified code in my controller:

```
DataBaseData = await Task.Run( () => GetDataFunction()  );
```

GetDataFunction is a function that will open a database connection, open a reader and read the data from the database.

In many examples I see it handled differently. The GetDataFunction itself is awaited. And within the function every single step is awaited.
For example:

- connection.OpenAsync
- reader.ReadAsycnc
- reader.IsDBNullAsync

Why is this good practice? Why not just start a thread for the whole database access (with Task.Run)?

**Update:** 
Thanks for the help. Now I got it. I did not get, that the asynchronous Api's do not start threads themselves. This really helped:  [blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: It is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298946/why-use-async-await-over-normal-threading-or-tasks

Comment: I unserstand how async/await works. But I don't get why I need the granular async/await handling in a WebApi Controller. There it is used to make sure that a request thread is returned to the pool. And just await Task.Run will do the same.

Comment: can someone explain me why I get a downvote on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you linked to states:

> You can kick off some background work by awaiting Task.Run, but there’s no point in doing so. In fact, that will actually hurt your scalability by interfering with the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics... As a general rule, don’t queue work to the thread pool on ASP.NET.

In other words, avoid `Task.Run` on ASP.NET.

> Why is this good practice? Why not just start a thread for the whole database access (with Task.Run)?

It's because the asynchronous APIs *do not use other threads*. The entire point of `async`/`await` is to free up the current thread; *not* use another thread. I have a blog post describing [how `async` works without needing threads](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

So, the `Task.Run` (or custom thread) approach will use up (block) a thread while getting data from the database. Proper asynchronous methods (e.g., EF6 or the ADO.NET asynchronous APIs) do not; they allow the request thread to be used for other requests while that request is waiting for the database response.

Comment: thanks man! this article helped a lot: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are wondering why using

```
await Task.Run(() => GetDataFunction());
```

instead of

```
await GetDataFunction();
```

As you can see in [Task.Run(Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382(v=vs.110).aspx) under the section *Remarks* there is written:

> The Run(Func) method is used by language compilers to support the async and await keywords. It is not intended to be called directly from user code.

That means, you should use `await GetDataFunction`.

Comment: ok, you're right. Task.Run should not be used. Nevertheless, what if I just spawn a new thread in the usual way?
I mean, the main question is, is it necessary to use the very granular handling and await every single step of the sql reading operations, or is it also fine to have the whole database operation stuff executed in a seperate thread. And this is all about request pooling in Webapi controllers, not about UI related async/await.

Comment: If you do not update GUI related items in the Task you can span the Task over all database operations. But then it is suggested to use the `non-async` methods on the db-connection.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about resource management and sharing.

When using `connection.Open()` method the thread that calls it has to wait for the connection to actually open. While waiting it does nothing but consume the CPU slice allocated to it by the operating system. However, when you `await connection.OpenAsync()` the thread frees up its resources and the OS can redistribute them to other threads.

Now, there's a catch: to actually gain from asynchronous calls they should take longer than the time it takes for the OS to switch contexts otherwise it will incur a drop in application performance.

The practice of awaiting on `connection.OpenAsync()`, `reader.ReadAsync()` etc. is due to the fact that these are *potentially* long running operations. In a system where de database resides on another machine and it is under a heavy load of requests, connecting to the database and getting the results of a query will take some time. Instead of blocking the CPU while waiting on the results to arrive why not allocate that time slice to another worker thread that waits in the scheduler queue to render the response for another client?

Now, about starting another thread for data access: **don't do that!**. Each new thread gets allocated about 1MB of memory space so beside wasting CPU time while waiting for database operations to finish you'll be wasting memory also. Furthermore, having such a heavy memory footprint would require a lot more runs for Garbage Collector which *will freeze all of your threads when running*.

Using `Task.Run()` will schedule the data access operations on a thread from the `ThreadPool` but you will lose the benefit of sharing the CPU time with another thread while waiting for database server to respond.