# Async library method usage in non-async methods

Tags: c#, async-await

I have created a logging library and the log method returns an error number (PK), upon making an entry into DB, which I notify to users as part of the error message on their UI. They further use that key as a reference when they talk to support team.

And I have an async method for doing the same, as below:

```
public class Logger
{
  public async Task<string> LogAsync(Exception ex)
  {
    return await DoLogAsync(ex);
  } 

  // some private method, with multiple optional parameters
  private Task<string> DoLogAsync(Exception ex)
  {
    return Task.Run(() => Log(ex));
  }
}
```

**Note:** I admit, this async version is nothing but simply wraps the synchronous method, Log(), in Task.Run. I am not sure, what else should be done!!

Now, i’m planning to use the above Log() method, in all my APIs, like below:

```
public Result<MyObject> Get()
{
  var result = new Result<MyObject>();

  try
  {
    throw new DivideByZeroException();
  }
  catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
  {
    string errorId = await _logger.LogAsync(ex);
    response.AddErrorMessage("Please Contact Admin with this error #"+errorId);
  }

  return result;
}
```

In order to make above work, I need to make the API method async, since i am awaiting the logger call.

1. How should I avoid changing my API call async, just for the sake of Logger? What are other possibilities of making this work?
2. Do you think, `LogAsync()` would really be beneficial? My UI thread will be waiting for the error number to be returned anyways, so why not just call the sync method?
3. There are few `Log()` methods, which doesn’t need an error number, in return, kind of log-and-forget. Do you think, async versions, will be helpful in such scenarios, because UI won’t expect anything back?

**Answer:** For the question 1, this works: [Waiting for async/await inside a task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task)

Also for 2, and 3, having ADO.Net implementations make much sense, rather than Task.Run

Comment: Is this a web app?

Comment: that is c#... please mid the tags :)

Comment: C# is a language. You can use C# for ASP.Net apps as well as Web APIs.

Comment: Yes! WebAPI for now but we have many other consumers

Comment: So.. in that case you know that c# is running over your **server**... anyhow.. please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777253/waiting-for-async-await-inside-a-task

Comment: What does `Log` method do? Please be specific, maybe even post the code.

Comment: @ymz, that answers my question 1. thanks

Comment: @CodingYoshi, Log() method actually creates a log entry into SQL database and returns the primary key, just inserted.

Comment: @Skip... thanks for your kind feedback...please edit your post and share the link and solution in **bold** - that may be useful to others (who don't read the entire comments block - shame on you lol)

Comment: In a web api, you should try and doing everything on one thread. Async does not mean you need to start a new thread. Make your action async and call the asynchronous version of the log method and await it without starting a task and delegating the work to a thread pool thread.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, thanks.. i'll keep that in mind

Comment: You may want to read [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/) by Stephen Toub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Web API I would not go for an `async` `Log` method if the method is not *truly* `async`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33606696/c-sharp-webapi-await-task-run-vs-more-granualar-await) answer from Stephen Cleary.

Comment: wow.. so i do not need to expose an async method; rather i would utilize ADO.Net async methods inside.. thanks

Comment: If you're using ADO.Net in your app for DB access, then yes, you should use its `async` methods. This means that your `Log` method will still be `async` tho, but you don't have to wrap it in a `Task.Run`

Comment: thanks for further advise. Yes; i am able to successfully utilize them

Comment: No. For this answer to be more accurate it should say: do not use `Task.Run` in a web or a web service scenario even if the method is truly async. Especially when it is not truly async.

Comment: @johanp read my comment again. According to your answer, without reading the link, if log method is truly async then it's ok to use task.run

Comment: Your comment is wrong and that is NOT what it says. Why would I tell op to not use Task.Run but then say it is ok to use it if the method is truly async. Are you kidding me?

Answer (score 0):

If you start using `async-await` approach in your code - be aware that `async` will spread over whole pipeline of your application.

So

> How should I avoid changing my API call async, just for the sake of
>   Logger? What are other possibilities of making this work?

Answer: Do not use `async`

> Do you think, LogAsync() would really be beneficial? My UI thread will
>   be waiting for the error number to be returned anyways, so why not
>   just call the sync method?

Answer: Benefit is that during waiting, UI will be "responsive" - user for example will be able to move window of the application on another screen or minimize it.

> There are few Log() methods, which doesn’t need an error number, in
>   return, kind of log-and-forget. Do you think, async versions, will be
>   helpful in such scenarios, because UI won’t expect anything back?

Answer: same as previous answer

Comment: Thanks; So, Instead of making the API async, I would like to use as below, as someone suggested in another post:
`var t = Task.Run( async () => { await lIB.LogAsync(); });`
Any side affects to that approach, you think?

Comment: Side effects: you wasting resources by reserving/creating another Thread only for doing nothing. In IO operation (which database query is) the thread will send request and wait for response.

Comment: thanks; It seems, i'll be better off w/o async in this scenario