# Use of await keyword in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a doubt. I have read that await keyword is used when we want to wait for a particular function to finish the operation.

```
public async void Work()
{
await SlowTask();
Console.WriteLine("Execution completed");
}
```

Now as per the definition, when Work() method is called, it will wait for SlowTask() method to complete its execution before printing "Execution completed". But I have a doubt that even if the await and async keyword are not used then also Work() method is going to wait for SlowTask() method to complete its execution before printing "Execution completed" because it will be executed line by line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Use Async/Await Over Normal Threading or Tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298946/why-use-async-await-over-normal-threading-or-tasks) and [How and When to use `async` and `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: For further clarification, I recommend giving [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming) article a read.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> But I have a doubt that even if the await and async keyword are not used then also Work() method is going to wait for SlowTask() method to complete its execution before printing "Execution completed" because it will be executed line by line.

If you don't use `await`, it will wait for the `SlowTask` method to *return* - but it won't wait for it to *complete*. This is one of the trickiest aspects of understanding async/await: an async method *returns* as soon as it needs to await something that hasn't finished, but then it continues when that has completed.

So suppose `SlowTask` is:

```
async Task SlowTask()
{
    Console.WriteLine("A");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("B");
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    Console.WriteLine("C");
}
```

This method will print `A` as soon as it's called, but will *return* when it hits the first `await`, because the delay won't have been completed. If you don't await `SlowTask` in your calling code, you'll then see "Execution completed" even though `SlowTask` hasn't really completed.

After the first delay has completed, `SlowTask` will resume, and `B` will be printed. It will return again (to whatever scheduled the continuation) due to the second delay, then continue and print `C` before *completing*. If you've actually awaited the task returned by `SlowTask` *that's* when you'll see "Execution completed" printed - which is probably what you want.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that always helped see the difference when I first came to learn about was this scenario.

```
Public async Task StartTaskAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Step");

    Task awaitableTask = OtherMethodAsync();

    Console.Writeline("Second step");
    await awaitableTask;
    Console.Writeline("4th Step");
}

Public async Task OtherMethodAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    Console.WriteLine("Step 3");
}
```

If you run this it will print out the steps in order. Because the await in the OtherMethodAsyncAsync passes control back to the calling method until whatever it is await has finished.

In the calling method StartTaskAsync it doesn't await immediately so it can continue to run some code until it waits on the task returned by the OtherMethodAsyncAsync.

If you were to make this synchronous. Ie remove all the asyncs and awaits and just return void rather than task. You would see that step 3 prints before Step 2