# QqsClient.SendMessageAsync without await doesn't work

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have a Lambda function and that lambda function is supposed to send messages to multiple queues in SQS and then exit,

If I add await, then messages are sent to all queues,

```
var sqsClient = ServerlessHelper.GetAmazonSqsClient();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(item.QueueUrl, item.Message);
}
```

But if I remove await from the code, then none of messages are sent to queues. I want to send messages in parallel. But due to await I have function cannot send messages in parallel. I am trying to do something like this,

```
var sqsClient = ServerlessHelper.GetAmazonSqsClient();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(item.QueueUrl, item.Message);
}
// wait until are messages are sent to queues.
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Just because a task is returned does not main that the library is thread safe. `async/await` allow for the current thread to be suspended so it can serve other requests while the IO operation is executed. It has nothing to do directly with TPL. See also [Difference between the TPL & async/await (Thread handling)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10286513/1260204)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(item.QueueUrl, item.Message);` returns a Task since it is an async function?

You need to save the task instances then use `Task.WhenAll` as in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17197786/9362652).

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible like this:

```
await Promise.all(
    items.map(item => 
        sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(item.QueueUrl, item.Message)
    )
)
```

The map function will create an array of promises. This array can be wrapped in a single promise by the `Promise.all` function, for which you can wait. This way, the promises will be resolved concurrently.

Comment: This is [tag:javascript] (or [tag:typescript]). The question is about [tag:c#]

Comment: Waauw. Totally did not spot that. I'm sorry. But I'm sure there will be a library or something that will do something similar. I'd try Googling for that.

Comment: Maybe but I am not the person that posted the question ;)