# Calling TaskCompletionSource.SetResult in a non blocking manner

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I've discovered that `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult();` invokes the code awaiting the task before returning. In my case that result in a deadlock.

This is a simplified version that is started in an ordinary `Thread`

```
void ReceiverRun()
    while (true)
    {
        var msg = ReadNextMessage();
        TaskCompletionSource<Response> task = requests[msg.RequestID];

        if(msg.Error == null)
            task.SetResult(msg);
        else
            task.SetException(new Exception(msg.Error));
    }
}
```

The "async" part of the code looks something like this.

```
await SendAwaitResponse("first message");
SendAwaitResponse("second message").Wait();
```

The Wait is actually nested inside non-async calls.

The SendAwaitResponse(simplified)

```
public static Task<Response> SendAwaitResponse(string msg)
{
    var t = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();
    requests.Add(GetID(msg), t);
    stream.Write(msg);
    return t.Task;
}
```

My assumption was that the second SendAwaitResponse would execute in a ThreadPool thread but it continues in the thread created for ReceiverRun.

Is there anyway to set the result of a task without continuing its awaited code?

The application is a **console application**.

Comment: A very simple workaround would be to do `Task.Run(() => task.SetResult(msg));` (and similarly with `SetException()`). But I hope there is a better option.

Comment: This blog post from 2018 discusses the issue and workarounds in detail: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-danger-of-taskcompletionsourcet-class/

Comment: Just the first sentence of your question was enough to enable me to figure out and fix my own deadlock. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);` when you want to force continuations added to the current task to be executed asynchronously.

Answer (score 39):

> I've discovered that TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(); invokes the code awaiting the task before returning. In my case that result in a deadlock.

Yes, I have a [blog post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) documenting this (AFAIK it's not documented on MSDN). The deadlock happens because of two things:

1. There's a mixture of `async` and blocking code (i.e., an `async` method is calling `Wait`).
2. Task continuations are scheduled using `TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously`.

I recommend starting with the simplest possible solution: removing the first thing (1). I.e., don't mix `async` and `Wait` calls:

```
await SendAwaitResponse("first message");
SendAwaitResponse("second message").Wait();
```

Instead, use `await` consistently:

```
await SendAwaitResponse("first message");
await SendAwaitResponse("second message");
```

If you need to, you can `Wait` at an alternative point further up the call stack (*not* in an `async` method).

That's my most-recommended solution. However, if you want to try removing the second thing (2), you can do a couple of tricks: either wrap the `SetResult` in a `Task.Run` to force it onto a separate thread (my [AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TaskCompletionSourceExtensions&referringTitle=Documentation) has `*WithBackgroundContinuations` extension methods that do exactly this), or give your thread an actual context (such as my [`AsyncContext` type](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext&referringTitle=Documentation)) and specify `ConfigureAwait(false)`, which will [cause the continuation to ignore the `ExecuteSynchronously` flag](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/07/10265067.aspx).

But those solutions are much more complex than just separating the `async` and blocking code.

As a side note, take a look at [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx); it sounds like you may find it useful.

Comment: To wrap SetResult in a Task.Run works!

To set the context looks interesting I will look into that.
The code calling SendAwaitResponse is what could be condered not under my control so my goal was to keep ReceiverRun continue to deliver messages even if a single await continuation decides to use Wait or any other time consuming operations.

Comment: There is now also the [TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions(v=vs.110).aspx#idMembers) method which allows you to specify (in the TaskCompletionSource constructor) that the continuations should be executed asynchronously. It is .NET 4.6+ only, however.

Comment: SetResult should just flag a task as complete, and it's continuations should run whenever a thread pool thread becomes available. If SetResult is blocking waiting on that to happen, that should be filed as a serious bug.

Comment: @Triynko: I [reported it as a bug](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html) 7 years ago. IIRC, it was closed as "by design".

Comment: `If SetResult is blocking waiting on that to happen` that just got me as well. 7-year-old-by-design-bug aaaw..

Comment: This was a great answer I've had to add some modern code in an old 4.5 system for new types of communication and specific actions caused blocking that broke everything. This solved the problem

Answer (score 6):

As your app is a console app, it runs on the default [synchronization context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext.aspx), where the `await` continuation callback will be called on the same thread the awaiting task has become completed on. If you want to switch threads after `await SendAwaitResponse`, you can do so with `await Task.Yield()`:

```
await SendAwaitResponse("first message");
await Task.Yield(); 
// will be continued on a pool thread
// ...
SendAwaitResponse("second message").Wait(); // so no deadlock
```

You could further improve this by storing `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` inside `Task.Result` and comparing it to the current thread's id after the `await`. If you're still on the same thread, do `await Task.Yield()`.

While I understand that `SendAwaitResponse` is a simplified version of your actual code, it's still completely synchronous inside (the way you showed it in your question). Why would you expect any thread switch in there?

Anyway, you probably should redesign your logic the way it doesn't make assumptions about what thread you are currently on. Avoid mixing `await` and `Task.Wait()` and make all of your code asynchronous. Usually, it's possible to stick with just one `Wait()` somewhere on the top level (e.g. inside `Main`).

**[EDITED]** Calling `task.SetResult(msg)` from `ReceiverRun` actually transfers the control flow to the point where you `await` on the `task` - without a thread switch, because of the default synchronization context's behavior. So, your code which does the actual message processing is taking over the `ReceiverRun` thread. Eventually, `SendAwaitResponse("second message").Wait()` is called on the same thread, causing the deadlock.

Below is a console app code, modeled after your sample. It uses `await Task.Yield()` inside `ProcessAsync` to schedule the continuation on a separate thread, so the control flow returns to `ReceiverRun` and there's no deadlock.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        class Worker
        {
            public struct Response
            {
                public string message;
                public int threadId;
            }

            CancellationToken _token;
            readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> _messages = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
            readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<Response>> _requests = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, TaskCompletionSource<Response>>();

            public Worker(CancellationToken token)
            {
                _token = token;
            }

            string ReadNextMessage()
            {
                // using Thread.Sleep(100) for test purposes here,
                // should be using ManualResetEvent (or similar synchronization primitive),
                // depending on how messages arrive
                string message;
                while (!_messages.TryDequeue(out message))
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }
                return message;
            }

            public void ReceiverRun()
            {
                LogThread("Enter ReceiverRun");
                while (true)
                {
                    var msg = ReadNextMessage();
                    LogThread("ReadNextMessage: " + msg);
                    var tcs = _requests[msg];
                    tcs.SetResult(new Response { message = msg, threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId });
                    _token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested(); // this is how we terminate the loop
                }
            }

            Task<Response> SendAwaitResponse(string msg)
            {
                LogThread("SendAwaitResponse: " + msg);
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();
                _requests.TryAdd(msg, tcs);
                _messages.Enqueue(msg);
                return tcs.Task;
            }

            public async Task ProcessAsync()
            {
                LogThread("Enter Worker.ProcessAsync");

                var task1 = SendAwaitResponse("first message");
                await task1;
                LogThread("result1: " + task1.Result.message);
                // avoid deadlock for task2.Wait() with Task.Yield()
                // comment this out and task2.Wait() will dead-lock
                if (task1.Result.threadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                    await Task.Yield();

                var task2 = SendAwaitResponse("second message");
                task2.Wait();
                LogThread("result2: " + task2.Result.message);

                var task3 = SendAwaitResponse("third message");
                // still on the same thread as with result 2, no deadlock for task3.Wait()
                task3.Wait();
                LogThread("result3: " + task3.Result.message);

                var task4 = SendAwaitResponse("fourth message");
                await task4;
                LogThread("result4: " + task4.Result.message);
                // avoid deadlock for task5.Wait() with Task.Yield()
                // comment this out and task5.Wait() will dead-lock
                if (task4.Result.threadId == Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
                    await Task.Yield();

                var task5 = SendAwaitResponse("fifth message");
                task5.Wait();
                LogThread("result5: " + task5.Result.message);

                LogThread("Leave Worker.ProcessAsync");
            }

            public static void LogThread(string message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, thread: {1}", message, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Worker.LogThread("Enter Main");
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000); // cancel after 5s
            var worker = new Worker(cts.Token);
            Task receiver = Task.Run(() => worker.ReceiverRun());
            Task main = worker.ProcessAsync();
            try
            {
                Task.WaitAll(main, receiver);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
            }
            Worker.LogThread("Leave Main");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

This is not much different from doing `Task.Run(() => task.SetResult(msg))` inside `ReceiverRun`. The only advantage I can think of is that you have an explicit control over when to switch threads. This way, you can stay on the same thread for as long as possible (e.g., for `task2`, `task3`, `task4`, but you still need another thread switch after `task4` to avoid a deadlock on `task5.Wait()`).

Both solutions would eventually make the thread pool grow, which is bad in terms of performance and scalability.

Now, if we **replace `task.Wait()` with `await task`** everywhere inside `ProcessAsync` in the above code, we will not have to use `await Task.Yield` and there still will be no deadlocks. However, the whole chain of `await` calls after the 1st `await task1` inside `ProcessAsync` will actually be executed on the `ReceiverRun` thread. As long as we don't block this thread with other `Wait()`-style calls and don't do a lot of CPU-bound work as we're processing messages, this approach might work OK (asynchronous IO-bound `await`-style calls still should be OK, and they may actually trigger an implicit thread switch).

That said, I think you'd need a separate thread with a serializing synchronization context installed on it for processing messages (similar to `WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext`). That's where your asynchronous code containing `awaits` should run. You'd still need to avoid using `Task.Wait` on that thread. And if an individual message processing takes a lot of CPU-bound work, you should use `Task.Run` for such work. For async IO-bound calls, you could stay on the same thread.

You may want to look at `ActionDispatcher`/`ActionDispatcherSynchronizationContext` from [@StephenCleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s 
[Nito Asynchronous Library](http://nitoasync.codeplex.com/) for your asynchronous message processing logic. Hopefully, Stephen jumps in and provides a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

"My assumption was that the second SendAwaitResponse would execute in a ThreadPool thread but it continues in the thread created for ReceiverRun."

It depends entirely on what you do within SendAwaitResponse.  Asynchrony and concurrency [are not the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844637/what-is-the-difference-between-concurrency-parallelism-and-asynchronous-methods).

Check out: [C# 5 Async/Await - is it *concurrent*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663101/c-sharp-5-async-await-is-it-concurrent)

Comment: I added that my application is a console application, still the top answer suggest that it then would continue in a thread pool thread, which did not happen.

Comment: Stream.Write is a synchronous method, you might want to use WriteAsync

Comment: @Slugart Sure, but using `WriteAsync()` wouldn't fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but here's my solution which i think is added value.

I've been struggling with this also, i've solved it by capturing the SynchronizationContext on the method that is awaited.

It would look something like:

```
// just a default sync context
private readonly SynchronizationContext _defaultContext = new SynchronizationContext();

void ReceiverRun()
{
    while (true)    // <-- i would replace this with a cancellation token
    {
        var msg = ReadNextMessage();
        TaskWithContext<TResult> task = requests[msg.RequestID];

        // if it wasn't a winforms/wpf thread, it would be null
        // we choose our default context (threadpool)
        var context = task.Context ?? _defaultContext;

        // execute it on the context which was captured where it was added. So it won't get completed on this thread.
        context.Post(state =>
        {
            if (msg.Error == null)
                task.TaskCompletionSource.SetResult(msg);
            else
                task.TaskCompletionSource.SetException(new Exception(msg.Error));
        });
    }
}

public static Task<Response> SendAwaitResponse(string msg)
{
    // The key is here! Save the current synchronization context.
    var t = new TaskWithContext<Response>(SynchronizationContext.Current); 

    requests.Add(GetID(msg), t);
    stream.Write(msg);
    return t.TaskCompletionSource.Task;
}

// class to hold a task and context
public class TaskWithContext<TResult>
{
    public SynchronizationContext Context { get; }

    public TaskCompletionSource<TResult> TaskCompletionSource { get; } = new TaskCompletionSource<Response>();

    public TaskWithContext(SynchronizationContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }
}
```