# AppDomain.Unload throws ThreadAbortException exception

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, appdomain

*Having*

```
public class ObjFromOtherAppDomain : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public async void Do(MarshalableCompletionSource<bool> source)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        source.SetResult(true);
    }
}

public class MarshalableCompletionSource<T> : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<T> tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();

    public void SetResult(T result) => tsc.SetResult(result);
    public void SetException(Exception[] exception) => tsc.SetException(exception);
    public void SetCanceled() => tsc.SetCanceled();

    public Task<T> Task => tsc.Task;
}
```

*Doing*

- Create new `AppDomain`
- Create an instance of `ObjFromOtherAppDomain` within the new `AppDomain`
- invoke `Do` method passing `MarshalableCompletionSource` in order later to know when `async` `Do` method is completed.
- Once `Do` method is completed, trying to `Unload` the `AppDomain`

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var otherDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("other domain");
    var objFromOtherAppDomain = (ObjFromOtherAppDomain)otherDomain        
      .CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
          typeof(ObjFromOtherAppDomain).Assembly.FullName, 
          typeof(ObjFromOtherAppDomain).FullName);

    var source = new MarshalableCompletionSource<bool>();
    objFromOtherAppDomain.Do(source);
    await source.Task;

    //await Task.Yield();

    AppDomain.Unload(otherDomain);
}
```

*Getting*

> System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: 'Thread has aborted. (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131530) exception

*Fix*

Uncomment `await Task.Yield();` line and `Unload` works well.

*Short analysis*

Main thread enters `Do` method and on the line `await Task.Delay(1000)`, Main thread returns back to `Main` method, while new background thread gets pulled from `ThreadPool` (it's happening in `otherDomain`) and continues execution of *continuation*, in this case, rest of the `Do` method.

After that, the **same** (background) thread starts executing rest of the `Main` method (the part after `await source.Task`)

At that moment background thread hits `AppDomain.Unload(otherDomain)`, it should be done in `otherDomain` and happily unload it, but, apparently, it's not.

If i'll yield (release, set free) **that background** thread by `await Task.Yield()`, new Background thread comes into play and does `AppDomain.Unload` happily.

Why is that?

Comment: `async void` is only meant for event handlers. It results in a fire-and-forget task that can't be awaited. That task may still be running when the application or ... application domain that launched it terminates. Use `async Task` if you want an asynchronous function that doesn't return anything. If you *don't* want the application to terminate before the task does, you'll have to wait for it

Comment: You could replicate this problem quite easily by using an `async Task Main()` and inside it call an `async void` method that waits eg for 10 seconds before trying to access a global object.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos correct, `async void` is there to support event handlers, but you can't really use `Task` here instead since `Task` isn't serializable and can't be used cross app-domain. That's why I'm passing `MarshalableCompletionSource` to `Do` method to *Wait* for its completion.

Comment: You can't *not* use `async Task` or `async ValueTask`. That's the invariant. What are you trying to do in the first place? There are probably other, better ways to do it. If you want two whatevers to communicate, you can use [Channels](https://ndportmann.com/system-threading-channels/), similar to Go's channels

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I want to run some task in new AppDomain and signal original appdomain whenever its done. I'll check out Channels, looks interesting. Thought, i still wanna understand why above exception is thrown.

Comment: DId you get you MarshallableCompletionSource from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/28277f25-5f5d-4b7c-bf1f-402937fc9f31/tasks-across-appdomain?forum=parallelextensions ? Seems similar :) After I started using it, I have almost exactly the same problem with ThreadAbortExceptions - but a different kind of them. I get exceptions stating "Unable to reset abort because no abort was requested". Funny exception. I don't see much problem with cancelling something that doesn't exist, and yet the platform authors did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of my colleague, I found out the issue.

*Short*

When the result is set to `TaskCompletionSource`, continuation attached to `TaskCompletionSource.Task` runs on **the same** thread that called `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult`, causing `Do` method not to be completed at the time `AppDomain.Unload` is called.

*Detailed*

1. `Main` -> `objFromOtherAppDomain.Do(source);` - `Thread1` starts execution of `Do` method
2. `Do` -> `await Task.Delay(1000);` - `Thread1` returns back to `Main` method and awaits `source.Task`, `Thread2` continues execution of `Do` method.
3. `Do` -> `source.SetResult(true);` - `Thread2` sets the result to `MarshalableCompletionSource.Task` and **continues execution of Main method** (Without finishing up the `Do` method)
4. `Main` -> `AppDomain.Unload(otherDomain);` - `Thread2` tries to unload the `AppDomain`, but since `Do` method isn't yet finished, unload fails.

On the other hand, if we do `await Task.Yield()`, it will cause `Thread2` to return from `Main` method to `Do` method and finish it up, after that `AppDomain` can be unloaded.

*Related*

[Calling TaskCompletionSource.SetResult in a non blocking manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481964/calling-taskcompletionsource-setresult-in-a-non-blocking-manner)